# Timeout exception for deleting record with primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2019, entity-framework-plus

I use EF Core 6.0 and `EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore` 6.14.

I use the following method to delete a record from a table:

```
public void DeleteDocument(int id) 
{
    using var ctx = this.CreateContext();
    ctx.ArticleDocuments.Where(x => x.Id == id).Delete();
}
```

When I execute the delete, I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Der Wartevorgang wurde abgebrochen.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()   at Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.BatchDelete.<>c.?(DbCommand ?)   at Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.BatchDelete.Execute[T](IQueryable`1 query)
> at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.BatchDeleteExtensions.Delete[T](IQueryable`1 query, Action`1 batchDeleteBuilder)
> at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.BatchDeleteExtensions.Delete[T](IQueryable`1 query)
> at E3kWebshopInterface.Data.Repositories.ArticleDocumentRepository.DeleteDocument(Int32 id) in D:\DATEN\Projekte\M-TECH\E3kWebshop\E3kWebshopInterface\E3kWebshopInterface\Data\Repositories\ArticleDocumentRepository.cs:line 77
> at E3kWebshopInterface.Controllers.ArticleDocumentController.RunDocuments(ArticleIdx idx) in D:\DATEN\Projekte\M-TECH\E3kWebshop\E3kWebshopInterface\E3kWebshopInterface\Controllers\ArticleDocumentController.cs:line 93
>
> ClientConnectionId:75232be6-9dfa-4c4c-8b5f-ff7bf471a3fa
> Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11

This is my mapping:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity 
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleDocument : BaseEntity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string E3kArticleKey { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PepperArticleKey { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DocumentHash { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsImage { get; set; }
}
```

The database is on SQL Server 2019. The table `ArticleDocument` contains 800 rows and `Id` is the primary key. My application is the one and only which uses the database and there is only one instance running.

I can't explain why a timeout can occur here.

**Edited at 29.August 2022**

This is the Query-Plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1wC0Scko

Comment: If there are foreign keys to this table (from other tables) and that column is not indexed, then to ensure the foreign key consistency the server will need to scan the whole table.

Comment: @Charlieface No ForeignKey. In the Database is only one table: ActivityDocuments (and __EFMigrationsHistory)

Comment: Can you grab a query plan (using XEvents, or SQL Profiler, or by querying `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` and `sys.dm_exec_query_plan`? Please upload it to https://pastetheplan.com and share the link

Comment: @Charlieface I have included the plan in the question.

Comment: Hmmm, the query plan has no SQL, did you remove it? Seeing as it's a single row delete on the clustered index, it shouldn't timeout. I'm guessing there is some kind of locking issue. Are you using multiple connections (or `DbContext`) at the same time? Are you using explicit transactions in the client scope? Are you making sure you always dispose your objects correctly with `using`?

Comment: @Charlieface I think, I have found the problem. I have implemented an Iterator-Method in my repository which do select on ActivityDocument and yield returns the entities to the controller. The controller do the iteration and tries to delete some entities. The Delete uses a new DataContext in the Repository because it will be created in the calling methods.

Comment: Sounds like it's locking up the database while it's doing that. I suggest you do `.ToList` somewhere, also use the same context